# Can CL_SALV_TABLE display a toolbar above the grid, as does CL_GUI_ALV_GRID?

Tags: oop, abap, alv

I have created a report using `CL_SALV_TABLE`, now I want to use the toolbar as displayed by `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID` in the grid, is this thing possible?

(i.e. can `CL_SALV_TABLE` display the ALV grid in a container instead of full screen mode)

Comment: I guess you want to run `CL_SALV_TABLE` in a screen container like `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID` does. You do it during the call to `CL_SALV_TABLE=>FACTORY`.

Comment: I'll try this, thanks!

Comment: what means "over the grid"? give screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest code possible (the container is achieved here using a minimal trick, but you may also do it via custom containers in dynpro, CL_GUI_DOCKING_CONTAINER, and so on; moreover the toolbar is displayed only if at least one button/function is enabled):

```
PARAMETERS dummy.
AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  PERFORM display USING cl_gui_container=>screen0.

FORM display USING container TYPE REF TO cl_gui_container.
  SELECT * FROM sflight INTO TABLE @DATA(sflight_lines).
  CALL METHOD cl_salv_table=>factory
        EXPORTING
          r_container  = container
        IMPORTING
          r_salv_table = DATA(salv)
        CHANGING
          t_table      = sflight_lines.
  salv->get_functions( )->set_all( ).
  salv->display( ).
ENDFORM.
```

Comment: Yes I achieved it using a custom container in dynpro. thanks!